# where's the javadoc / other documentation for HTTPclient?

Tags: javadoc, httpclient

I get a 404 Not Found from http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.0.1/httpclient/apidocs/index.html -- does anyone know where the httpclient 4.0.x javadoc lives? (directed to that link from http://hc.apache.org/user-docs.html)

The Primer is also missing http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/primer.html

Comment: [Pretty fail, apache...](http://old.nabble.com/httpclient-javadoc-404's-td29778240.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [filed a bug w/ apache](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1013) and they fixed it.

Comment: Argh.  Its "unfixed" now.  Sometimes I love Apache.  This isn't one of those times.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the JavaDocs are also included in the [download packages](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi).

Answer (score 0):

The latest GA javadocs can be found here: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/index.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this links to the documentation for 4.3.x, not 4.0.x as requested in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a full tutorial which Apache recently added.
https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/ 
It has both HTML and PDF versions.